# Query through PreparedStatement in H2 throws exception: This method is not allowed for a prepared statement; use a regular statement instead

Tags: sql, exception, select, h2, executequery

A simple query fails when run through a prepared statement while using JDBC 4 to access an [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) database in Java 11.

When running this line:

```java
try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
```

…I get this error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: This method is not allowed for a prepared statement; use a regular statement instead. [90130-197]

I tried using the [H2 Error Analyzer](http://h2database.com/html/sourceError.html), but no help there.

Here is a complete example app, in a single .java file. You can copy-paste and run yourself.

```
package com.basilbourque.example.work.basil.example.h2.pstmt_query;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {

        // Create database.
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:pstmt_query_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ); // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
        dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );

        // Create table.
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE person_ ( \n" +
                    " pkey_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                    " name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL \n" +
                    ");";
            System.out.println( sql );
            stmt.execute( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Query table.
        List < UUID > list = new ArrayList <>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM person_ WHERE name_ = ? ;";
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
        ) {
            String name = "Wendy Melvoin";
            pstmt.setString( 1 , name );
            try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {  // org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: This method is not allowed for a prepared statement; use a regular statement instead. [90130-197]
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
                    list.add( pkey );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Exception reported:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: This method is not allowed for a prepared statement; use a regular statement instead. [90130-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:302)
    at com.basilbourque.example.work.basil.example.h2.pstmt_query.App.doIt(App.java:53)
    at com.basilbourque.example.work.basil.example.h2.pstmt_query.App.main(App.java:13)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Passing the SQL string twice

On a `PreparedStatement`, you never pass the SQL string to `executeQuery` method. You do so in an unprepared `Statement`, but not `PreparedStatement`. Notice how the JavaDoc for [`PreparedStatement::executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) takes no argument.

So your line:

```
try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
```

…should be:

```
try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery() ; ) {
```

You already passed the SQL string named `sql` above that line, when you prepared the statement:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
```

Since the `PreparedStatement` named `pstmt` already holds your SQL statement(s), there is no need to pass into `executeQuery`.

This mistake might have been the result of copy-pasting some code using `Statement` for reuse in some other code using `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I am afraid that your answer, a very common mistake which people make, will be hidden by your title, which talks about H2 database.  By the way, many tutorials commit this sin too.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the feedback. My Question actually is rather H2-specific, as searching the internets for H2’s particular error message (with or without the code number at the end) failed to find anything helpful. So I wanted to plant the specifics here for posterity – and for me when I forget about this and repeat my mistake in six months again.

Comment: As for repeating my mistake… happened today, and here I am reading this page with a chuckle.

Comment: This is a mistake of the API designers too. JDBC is just strange.